# Google Analytics - Tracking Song Plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, tracking

Since I'm using a Javascript to play HTML5 audio, would it be possible to somehow integrate a script that would send the amount of play requests for each song and the title to Google Analytics?

I'm not too familiar with Google analytics, so I'm not sure if this would even be possible.

Has anyone ever tried this before?

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.ubaplayer.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer({
            codecs: [{name:"MP3", codec: 'audio/mpeg;'}]
            });

    });
    jQuery('a[rel=vidbox]').click(function () {

        if (jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("playing") === true) {
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("pause");
            }
        return false;
    });
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ubaPlayer"></div>
    <ul class="controls">
        <li><a class="audioButton" href="mp3/dontthinktwice.mp3">
        Don't Think Twice (Bob Dylan)</a></li>
        <li><a class="audioButton" href="mp3/livingforthecity.mp3">
        Living for the City (Stevie Wonder)</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**Audio Player Javascript:**

```
(function($) {
var defaults = {
    audioButtonClass: "audioButton",
    autoPlay: null,
    codecs: [{
        name: "OGG",
        codec: 'audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'
    }, {
        name: "MP3",
        codec: 'audio/mpeg'
    }],
    continuous: false,
    extension: null,
    flashAudioPlayerPath: "libs/swf/player.swf",
    flashExtension: ".mp3",
    flashObjectID: "audioPlayer",
    loadingClass: "loading",
    loop: false,
    playerContainer: "player",
    playingClass: "playing",
    swfobjectPath: "libs/swfobject/swfobject.js",
    volume: 1
},
    currentTrack, isPlaying = false,
    isFlash = false,
    audio, $buttons, $tgt, $el, playTrack, resumeTrack, pauseTrack, methods = {
        play: function(element) {
            $tgt = element;
            currentTrack = _methods.getFileNameWithoutExtension($tgt.attr("href"));
            isPlaying = true;
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);

            if (isFlash) {
                if (audio) {
                    _methods.removeListeners(window);
                }
                audio = document.getElementById(defaults.flashObjectID);
                _methods.addListeners(window);
                audio.playFlash(currentTrack + defaults.extension);
            } else {
                if (audio) {
                    audio.pause();
                    _methods.removeListeners(audio);
                }
                audio = new Audio("");
                _methods.addListeners(audio);
                audio.id = "audio";
                audio.loop = defaults.loop ? "loop" : "";
                audio.volume = defaults.volume;
                audio.src = currentTrack + defaults.extension;
                audio.play();
            }
        },

        pause: function() {
            if (isFlash) {
                audio.pauseFlash();
            } else {
                audio.pause();
            }

            $tgt.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);
            isPlaying = false;
        },

        resume: function() {
            if (isFlash) {
                audio.playFlash();
            } else {
                audio.play();
            }
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.playingClass);
            isPlaying = true;
        },

        playing: function() {
            return isPlaying;
        }
    },

    _methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var types;

            //set defaults
            $.extend(defaults, options);
            $el = this;

            //listen for clicks on the controls
            $(".controls").bind("click", function(event) {
                _methods.updateTrackState(event);
                return false;
            });
            $buttons = $("." + defaults.audioButtonClass);

            types = defaults.codecs;
            for (var i = 0, ilen = types.length; i < ilen; i++) {
                var type = types[i];
                if (_methods.canPlay(type)) {
                    defaults.extension = [".", type.name.toLowerCase()].join("");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!defaults.extension || isFlash) {
                isFlash = true;
                defaults.extension = defaults.flashExtension;
            }

            if (isFlash) {
                $el.html("<div id='" + defaults.playerContainer + "'/>");
                $.getScript(defaults.swfobjectPath, function() {
                    swfobject.embedSWF(defaults.flashAudioPlayerPath, defaults.playerContainer, "0", "0", "9.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", false, false, {
                        id: defaults.flashObjectID
                    }, _methods.swfLoaded);
                });
            } else {
                if (defaults.autoPlay) {
                    methods.play(defaults.autoPlay);
                }
            }
        },

        updateTrackState: function(evt) {
            $tgt = $(evt.target);
            if (!$tgt.hasClass("audioButton")) {
                return;
            }
            if (!audio || (audio && currentTrack !== _methods.getFileNameWithoutExtension($tgt.attr("href")))) {
                methods.play($tgt);
            } else if (!isPlaying) {
                methods.resume();
            } else {
                methods.pause();
            }
        },

        addListeners: function(elem) {
            $(elem).bind({
                "canplay": _methods.onLoaded,
                "error": _methods.onError,
                "ended": _methods.onEnded
            });
        },

        removeListeners: function(elem) {
            $(elem).unbind({
                "canplay": _methods.onLoaded,
                "error": _methods.onError,
                "ended": _methods.onEnded
            });
        },

        onLoaded: function() {
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.playingClass);

            audio.play();
        },

        onError: function() {
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            if (isFlash) {
                _methods.removeListeners(window);
            } else {
                _methods.removeListeners(audio);
            }
        },

        onEnded: function() {
            isPlaying = false;
            $tgt.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);
            currentTrack = "";
            if (isFlash) {
                _methods.removeListeners(window);
            } else {
                _methods.removeListeners(audio);
            }

            if (defaults.continuous) {
                var $next = $tgt.next().length ? $tgt.next() : $(defaults.audioButtonClass).eq(0);
                methods.play($next);
            }

        },

        canPlay: function(type) {
            if (!document.createElement("audio").canPlayType) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return document.createElement("audio").canPlayType(type.codec).match(/maybe|probably/i) ? true : false;
            }
        },

        swfLoaded: function() {
            if (defaults.autoPlay) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    methods.play(defaults.autoPlay);
                }, 500);
            }
        },

        getFileNameWithoutExtension: function(fileName) {
            //this function take a full file name and returns an extensionless file name
            //ex. entering foo.mp3 returns foo
            //ex. entering foo returns foo (no change)
            var fileNamePieces = fileName.split('.');
            fileNamePieces.pop();
            return fileNamePieces.join(".");
        }
    };

$.fn.ubaPlayer = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
        return _methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jquery.ubaPlayer");
    }
};})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use Google Analytics event tracking for tracking any custom events:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Answer (score 1):

[How to Track JavaScript and Ajax Events with Google Analytics](http://www.sitepoint.com/google-analytics-track-javascript-ajax-events/) is a rather extensive tutorial, with examples of an mp3 system. So...yes!

Google Analytics allows you to track custom Events thrown from javascript. One example the site gives is:

> `if (_gaq) _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label, value]);`
>   Simple. The condition first checks that we have included the Analytics
>   JavaScript, then sends the details of the event itself. Typical events
>   from our MP3 system might be:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mp3system', 'search', 'good songs']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mp3system', 'view', 'song 1', 3456]);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mp3system', 'download', 'song 1', 3456]);
```

> For a file download, the simplest HTML would be:

```
<a href="file.mp3" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mp3system',
'download', 'file.mp3']);return true;">download</a>
```

And here's the appropriate Google documentation: [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)